# Why does common-pool2 using abandonedConfig have to do it like this: `final AbandonedConfig ac = this.abandonedConfig`?

Tags: pool

I read the source code in apache/commons-pool tonight and I found every time when reading the abandonedConfig, the code always is written like this:

```html
 final AbandonedConfig ac = this.abandonedConfig;
        if (ac != null && ac.getRemoveAbandonedOnBorrow() && (getNumIdle() < 2) &&
                (getNumActive() > getMaxTotal() - 3)) {
            removeAbandoned(ac);
        }
```

Please tell me why they do that? Why not do something like:

```html
if (abandonedConfig != null && abandonedConfig.getRemoveAbandonedOnBorrow() && (getNumIdle() < 2) &&
                    (getNumActive() > getMaxTotal() - 3)) {
                removeAbandoned(ac);
            }
```